# Crashing detect function in opencv(ORB and BRISK)

Tags: exception, detect, opencv3.0, orb, brisk

I'm trying to get the keypoints in a image using the detector ORB but always gets an exception and crash, my code is the next one.

```
vector < KeyPoint > kp;

int nfeatures = 500;
float scaleFactor = 1.2f;
int nlevels = 8;
int edgeThreshold = 15;
int firstLevel = 0;
int WTA_K = 2;
int scoreType = ORB::HARRIS_SCORE;
int patchSize = 31;
int fastThreshold = 20;

Ptr < ORB > detector = ORB::create(
    nfeatures,
    scaleFactor,
    nlevels,
    edgeThreshold,
    firstLevel,
    WTA_K,
    scoreType,
    patchSize,
    fastThreshold );

detector->detect(img, kp);
cout << "Found " << kp.size() << " Keypoints " << std::endl;

Mat out;
drawKeypoints(img, kp, out, Scalar::all(255));

imshow("Kpts", out);
```

img is declared early, the problem is when do detector->detect(img, kp); and I don't know what problem is, I'm trying other form of do it but all crash in the call of detect().

I try to do with BRISK and the problem is the same in the call of detect crash.
With brisk I did the next one for simplify:

```
Ptr < BRISK > detector = BRISK::create();
vector <KeyPoint> kp;
detector->detect(img,kp);
```

This is turning exasperating.

I using opencv 3 in visual studio 2015 with windows 10.

Sorry for my English and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error continues in CV2 version `4.2.0` actual for today. I have similarly tried to initialize with `cv2.ORB()`, received the `~00x5 error`, tried `ORB_create()` and it eventually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solve my problem building opencv for visual studio with cmake and the opencv_contrib, i follow the instructions of the next links if someone have the same problem:

http://audhootchavancv.blogspot.in/2015/08/how-to-install-opencv-30-and.html